# Linq expression orderBy on child collections

Tags: c#, linq

I've got this class with a collection of revisions:

```
public class Client : BaseEntity
{
   public virtual ICollection<Draw> Draws { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<ClientRevision> ClientRevisions { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class ClientRevision : BaseEntity
{
   public Guid ClientId { get; set; }
   public Client Client { get; set; }

   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public double? Increase { get; set; }

   public string RevisionCode { get; set; }
   public string RevisionNote { get; set; }
}
```

On controller, I'd like to retrieve the list of clients with the last revision available. I've got a base repository with the following get method:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAsync(
   Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
   Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
   IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, object>>> includeProperties = null,
   int? pageIndex = null,
   int? itemsPerPage = null,
   bool ignoreQueryFilter = true,
   bool ignoreTracking = true)
   {
      var query = DataContext.GetData<T>(ignoreTracking);

      if (filter != null)
      {
         query = query.Where(filter);
      }

      if (orderBy != null)
      {
         query = orderBy(query);
      }

      if (ignoreQueryFilter)
      {
         query = query.IgnoreQueryFilters();
      }

      query = ApplyIncludePropertiesIfNeeded(includeProperties, query);

      if (pageIndex.HasValue && itemsPerPage.HasValue)
      {
         query = query
         Skip(pageIndex.Value * itemsPerPage.Value)
         Take(itemsPerPage.Value + 1);
      }

      return await query.ToListAsync();
   }
```

I'd like to order by the list by the Name of the client; the name is in the Client Revision. I try to implement the following filter and orderby, but I cannot create a correct linq expression for retrive the Name of the Client.

```
public async Task<ActionResult<ClientResponse>> GetClientListAsync()
{
   var result = new List<ClientResponse>();

   List<Expression<Func<Client, object>>> includes = new() { i => i.Draws };

   var sortOn = "ClientRevisions.Name";
   var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Client), "client");
   var parts = sortOn.Split('.');
   Expression parent = param;

   foreach (var part in parts)
   {
      parent = Expression.Property(parent, part);
   }

   var sortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Client, object>>(parent, param);

   Func<IQueryable<Client>, IOrderedQueryable<Client>> order = o => o.OrderBy(sortExpression);
}
```

The error is the following:

> Instance property 'Name' is not defined for type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[ClientRevision]' (Parameter 'propertyName')

Because is a list. How to retrieve this data from a list? Thanks

Comment: It doesn't make sense, even if you write data on a paper you can not tell what result you want because it's a list in a list, you can sort your sub-collections but not the parent list.
another alternative is grouping the sub-collections by name and using the group name for the parent list

Comment: unlike ordering, this is a valid scenario for filtering(if you want to filter the Client list using the sub-collections data), I implemented this in The `Gridify` library.
https://github.com/alirezanet/Gridify/blob/20cb4941469cdc4dd095f362262f3a1094fa9f04/src/Gridify/Syntax/SyntaxTreeToQueryConvertor.cs#L51